# Python memcached set_multi storing issue

Tags: python, memcached, python-memcached

I have discovered an issue when trying to store a lot of keys using python-memcached.
Here is what I'm doing:

```
import memcache

# This dict has a 2270 entries that is generated on production server
v = eval(open("/home/dragoon/output").read())
a = memcache.Client(['unix:/tmp/memcached.sock'], debug=1)
```

Next I'm trying to set all these values:

```
In [94]: len(a.set_multi(v))                                       
MemCached: MemCache: unix:/tmp/memcached.sock: timed out.  Marking dead.
Out[94]: 2270
```

The log output of the memcached server:

```
...
27: going from conn_new_cmd to conn_parse_cmd
<27 set d750bde63a98579f9c2987907aaaf5f8 1 0 18
27: going from conn_parse_cmd to conn_nread
> FOUND KEY d750bde63a98579f9c2987907aaaf5f8
>27 STORED
27: going from conn_nread to conn_write
Failed to write, and not due to blocking: Broken pipe
27: going from conn_write to conn_closing
<27 connection closed.
```

After some time:

```
In [96]: len(a.set_multi({'test':1}))
Out[96]: 0

In [97]: a.get('test')
Out[97]: 1
```

Default timeout is 3 seconds, but increasing it even to 100 seconds doesn't help, memcached is just getting stucked.
So, my question is, what is the problem with memcache?

I saw people talking about storing over 1000 000 entries in it, but for me it can't even store 2 000?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. It seems that there is some bug in memcached 1.4.2 that is the last version in Ubuntu 10.04 LTS.
Memcached 1.4.5 works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Try using pylibmc as your memcache driver, rather than using python-memcache

I've seen this issue on Memcache 1.4.7 on Ubuntu 11 as well.

Comment: Unfortunately we're still using django 1.2, so pylibmc is not an option right now(

Comment: Error happens, too, with Memcached Version 1.4.13, native API (telnet) as client and php / pear memcached as client driver...